# Add a widget tile to Power BI report

Tags: html, forms, powerbi, widget

I'm looking to add a widget to a power bi report. I've found a few articles explaining how to add web content to a dashboard using the '+Add a tile' option from the Power BI online service.

Links to articles:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-bi-how-to-add-web-content-to-dashboard/

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Add-a-widget-to-a-Power-BI-report/td-p/2409811

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-dashboard-add-widget

[image]

However, I do not see the '+Add a tile' option or even the 'Edit' dropdown. All I have is an 'Edit' button which when pressed opens the editor. I've tried finding the option using search box and combing through the visuals pane and the ribbon. I even tried another route with the HTML viewer custom visual in desktop but that came with its own problems.

[image]

Also, I'm using gov.us but I'm not sure whether that has anything to do with the issue.

For reference, here is the widget code I'd like to use: `<div class="embedsocial-forms-iframe" data-ref="71104d53274b4f2bc8c8d7cb555a66f367abb5ca" data-widget="true" data-height="auto"></div><script>(function(d, s, id){var js; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "https://embedsocial.com/cdn/ef.js"; d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);}(document, "script", "EmbedSocialFormsScript"));</script>`

Any and all help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.